# RazorpayFlutterPlugin in class RazorpayFlutterPlugin cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, razorpay

D:\FlutterDevelopment\E-Grocery\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:25: error: constructor RazorpayFlutterPlugin in class RazorpayFlutterPlugin cannot be applied to given types;
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.razorpay.razorpay_flutter.RazorpayFlutterPlugin());
                                   ^
  required: Registrar
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: I'm facing the same issue.
razorpay_flutter: 1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

They have issue in new update 1.2.0
reverting back to 1.1.4 in pubspac.yaml will solve the problem

Steps:

- Remove the flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/razorpay_flutter-1.2.0
- change razorpay version to `razorpay_flutter: 1.1.4`
- run below commands

`$ flutter clean`

`$ flutter pub get`

`$ flutter build apk`